# Forcing cmake to choose location of dependency if more than one exist

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake

In directory `/home/karnivaurus/Project`, I have three files. I have a class file `Foo.cpp`, a shared library file `libBar.so`, and a `CMakeLists.txt` file. I also have a similar shared library, with the same name `libBar.so`, located at `/usr/lib`.

The `CMakeLists.txt` contains the following:

```
add_library(Foo SHARED Foo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Foo Bar)
```

After running `cmake`, the library compiles fine and creates `libFoo.so`. If I then run the command `ldd libFoo.so`, it indicates that there is a dependency on `/home/karnivaurus/Project/libBar.so`.

Now, I change things around and instead of creating a shared library, I want to create an executable, So, I create a new file `Main.cpp`, which calls functions in `Foo.cpp`, and change the `CMakeLists.txt` to:

```
add_executable(Foo Foo.cpp Main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Foo Bar)
```

This compiles fine, and creates an executable `Foo`. However, if I now run `ldd Foo`, it tells me there is a dependency on `/usr/lib/libBar.so`.

So my questions are:

1) Why does creating the shared library cause a dependency on the `libBar.so` file in the source directory, whereas creating the executable causes a dependency on the `libBar.so` file in the `usr/lib` directory?

2) How can I force cmake to create a dependency on one of these, rather than the other?

Answer (score 0):

### Answer to question 2

This should make `Foo` link `/home/karnivaurus/Project/libBar.so`:

```
link_directories( /home/karnivaurus/Project )
add_executable(Foo Foo.cpp Main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Foo Bar)
```

---

If that doesn't work you can always add the absolute path to the library in the call to `target_link_libraries`:

```
target_link_libraries(Foo /home/karnivaurus/Project/libBar.so)
```